# API Stopped Working for 2019 Medical Individual Landscape

Tags: socrata, soda

It all the sudden stopped working last week, and it's no longer listed on data.healthcare.gov page.

Is it a technical error, or a policy issue that you no longer provide this data?  Or is there a new link and can you please provide it?

For example:
https://data.healthcare.gov/resource/itgc-a3uf.json?state=IL&county=COOK

I have valid API key, so that's not an issue with credential and access.

Answer (score 1):

It does appear that the data set has been removed or hidden from public view. However, I would recommend that you [contact the maintainers](https://data.medicare.gov/contact-us) for advice.

Comment: On the their developer’s page [https://dev.socrata.com/](https://dev.socrata.com/), it asks us to post any questions for them here and add these specific tags. I thought that was weird too, but unfortunately they don’t provide any other way to get help.  Thanks for the down vote. I was just doing what I was told.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation credits to downvote -- that was someone else....Socrata doesn't control what data is posted, that depends on the data provider. On the Medicaid data portal, they referred to the above "contact the maintainers" link to contact them directly for data-related questions.

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation and I apologize for my erroneous judgement.